# Create method wont Create New Relationship in databse even though success flash appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, controller, action, url-routing

I'm trying to create a relationship in the database, but cant get it to work.
**why wont the create action work? why can't it find the if statement? I think i havent written the create action correctly in the relationships controller but don't know how to fix it**

When a user clicks 'add relationship'. the app should create the new relationship. 
At the moment a user clicks 'add relationship' and this flash success msg appears:

```
You are now connected !
```

this is the information that comes across to the view where the flash success msg appears:

relationships.html.erb

```
relationship: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  followed_id: '3'
commit: Add Relationship
action: create
controller: relationships
```

**but! a relationship is not created in the database**

Here is the flow users take with comments to help explain:

**users/index.html.erb**:

```
# 1. USER SEARCHES FOR ANOTHER USER IN SYSTEM:

<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

# 2. IF ANOTHER USER IS FOUND, THEIR NAME IS PRESENTED AND AN 'ADD RELATIONSHIP' BUTTON APPEARS:

<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
            <%= user.name %>
            <%= render 'followed', followed: user %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**_followed.html.erb**:

```
# 3. ADD RELATIONSHIP BUTTON INFORMATION. THE USER CLICKS THE BUTTON, RELATIONSHIPS/CREATE IS THE NEXT PAGE. NO RELATIONSHIP IS CREATED

<%= form_for :relationship, url: relationships_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="form form-actions">
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id, value: followed.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Relationship", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**relationships_controller**:

```
  def create
    if params[:relationship] && params[:relationship].has_key?(:followed_id)
      @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:active_relationship][:followed_id])
      @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.new(followed: @followed)
      @active_relationship.save
      flash[:success] = "You are now connected !"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Relationship required"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is in the second line in your create controller. In your if statement you have params[:relatioship] so I guess you would write

```
 @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:relationship][:followed_id])
```

and I guess the followed_id shouldn't be a `name`

You should refactor the code like this:

```
if params[:relationship] 
  @followed = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
  @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.new(followed: @followed)
  if @active_relationship.save
    flash[:success] = "You are now connected !"
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Relationship required"
  end
else
  flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong!!"
end
```

You might also use `pry` to debug codes. Links for reference http://pryrepl.org